# Create a HttpEntity

Tags: java, android, android-async-http, loopj

I'm trying to update to the latest version (1.4.9) of `com.loopj.android:android-async-http` where `org.apache.http` was replaced with `cz.msebera.android.httpclient`.

At the moment I use:

```
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity("some data");
client.post(static_context, getAbsoluteUrl(url), entity, "application/json", responseHandler);
```

So I thought I can just cast it to `HttpEntity` which is not the case.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity cannot be cast to cz.msebera.android.httpclient.HttpEntity
```

So my question is how can I create a `HttpEntity` with my data or is there a better way to create a post request with data in the body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you import the wrong `StringEntity` class.

Assuming the `cz.msebera.android.httpclient` still has a `StringEntity`, you should be able to

```
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.entity.StringEntity
```

instead of

```
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity
```

Comment: Well I assumed that to but it's not the case.

Comment: Hmm.. At some point a `org.apache.http.*` class is used, or else you wouldn't get this ClassCastException.

Comment: Ah yeah you are right the StringEntity is `org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity` but I didn't find a similar class in `cz.msebera.android.httpclient.`

Comment: ah sorry, maybe it's `cz.msebera.android.httpclient.entity.StringEntity`

Comment: I could have figured out that by myself m). It's just `cz.msebera.android.httpclient.entity.StringEntity` and not `cz.msebera.android.httpclient.StringEntity`